Не могу открыть терминал в pycharm
загрузил pycharm установил python и ввел первую команду print("") вбил ы терминал но не могу использовать терминал                      Cannot open Local                                   Failed to start [C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe] in C:\PyProjects\lampa, [columns=1                                    See IDE log (Help | Show Log in Explorer) for the details.

2 раза переустанавливал пайчарм, но какую версию советуете установить заново?

В прошлом при возникновений ошыбок сразу после установки мне помогала реинсталляция приложения или установкой другой версии PyCharm`a
